# How deserialized as an array but receives an object

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

To make a save using the resource, it needs to receive a deserialized as an array I'm getting like this .:

> nome=angularjs&telefone=%2B556639687898&cor=2&idoperadora=1
> with $jQuery.param(item) or .:

```
Object { nome: "angularjs", telefone: "+556639687898", idoperadora: "1", cor: "1" }
​
cor: "1"
​
idoperadora: "1"
​
nome: "angularjs"
​
telefone: "+556639687898"
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

native.
I've tried JSON.parse() but it didn't work.
How can I convert to expected resource save format?

Code.:

```
pessoas.factory("PessoasSrv", function ($http, $resource) {
    var baseUrl = "http://localhost/sisgestorv2/";

    return $resource(
        baseUrl + "contato/:id",
        {
            id: "@id",
        },
        {
            query: {
                method: "GET",
                isArray: true,
            },
            update: {
                method: "PUT",
                url: baseUrl + "contato/update/:id",
            },
            remove: {
                method: "DELETE",
                url: baseUrl + "contato/delete/:id",
            },
        }
    );
```

I've tried JSON.parse() but it didn't work.
How can I convert to expected resource save format?

Comment: Isn't the params query string an object? How could it be represented as an array?

Comment: to save using save, it is giving this error, it is asking to deserialize this json into something like `' { "nome": "angularjs", "telefone": "+556639687898", "idoperadora": "1", "cor": "1" }'`

Comment: There is no json format involved anywhere in this.